# Recursive object: works one way, but not the other

Tags: recursion, ocaml

Below are two examples, they are very simplified, and in this simplified form have no practical meaning, but it would help me to understand how things work using these two:

```
let test x = object (self)
  val x = x
  method testme = x == self
end in
Printf.printf "printme: %b\n" (test test)#testme;;

let test x = object
  method testme = (==) x
end in
Printf.printf "printme: %b\n" ((test test)#testme test);;
```

The first example doesn't work, while the second one does. The first one argues about types of `x` and `test` being incompatible, but I don't understand how does it come to the conclusion that the type of `x` is `< testme : bool > -> < testme : bool >`. Why not just `< testme : bool >`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I see:

```
# let test x = object (self) method testme = x == self end;;
val test : < testme : bool > -> < testme : bool > = <fun>
```

Indeed, `test` is a function and not an object. It has the form of a basic OCaml function definition. You say that `x` is a function, but `x` is the function parameter of `test`. So the type of `x` is `< testme: bool >`.